# What is assignment vs reference?

Tags: python, function, reference, global-variables, variable-assignment

I am new to Python. I am bit confused about how python function decides if a variable is referred or assigned. I think this determines whether the variable is global or local.

For example,

```
x = 1 #assignment
y = x + 1 #reference
x[0] = 1 #reference or assignment????
x += 1 #reference or assignment????
```

Is there any general rule that I don't know?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference This is the best explanation I've found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key question for global vs local is whether the name is bound by an assignment statement.

```
x = 1 #assignment
y = x + 1 #reference
```

right and right.

```
x[0] = 1 #reference or assignment????
```

This is a reference to `x`.  This statement is the same effect as `x.__setitem__(0, 1)`. It invokes a method on `x`.  It does not assign to the name `x`.

```
x += 1 #reference or assignment????
```

This is an assignment to `x`.  It has the same effect as `x = x.__iadd__(1)`.